# UINavigationbar from Storyboard does not fill or center properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have chosen my storyboard to auto layout subviews and auto resize.

This was in the hope to make it once and it'll works for everything. However, the navigation title doesn't properly center. However its obvious why since the title bar does not fill the screen in landscape mode.

[Animation here](http://zippy.gfycat.com/VerifiableInsistentCob.gif)

How can I, using the storyboard properties set the navigation bar to properly fill? I already know how to achieve this programatically. I would like to use apples default setting rather than making custom views.

Comment: can you please check attached .gif image link? I am not able to access it.

Comment: As said above, your gif is not viewable, but I can guess that your title is long enough and back button title too, so system shifts title to fit all content in the bar, this is expected behavior